# Android WebView: Audio stutters when phone is locked

Tags: android, audio, android-webview, html5-audio

I have an app that plays audio via `HTML5` `<audio>` in an embedded `WebView`.

The audio sounds great when the phone is unlocked. However, when the phone is locked, the audio continues playing, but it stutters. How can I fix this?

I see a lot of posts talking about using `MediaPlayer` in a service to play audio when the phone is locked. I would like to continue using `WebView` and the built-in audio player if at all possible. Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Comment: `WakeLock`, maybe? (Implies a required foreground service, for Oreo+).

Comment: @greeble31 Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, it doesn't look like that's it. I tried setting a WakeLock of type Partial (which explicitly keeps the CPU running even when the power button is pressed), but the stuttering didn't seem to change.

Comment: What if you leave the phone plugged in while the screen is off?

Comment: @greeble31 I tried it both plugged in and unplugged and it didn't make a difference. I also notice that just switching focus to another app causes the stuttering too.

Comment: @BrianRak Hi, I am facing the same issue as yours. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @RahulKumar I ended up changing the app to do playback through `MediaSession` / `MediaPlayer` / `MediaController` classes. It was a challenging overhaul, but it completely solved the stuttering issue. It has been a while since I coded this up, but I believe a good starting point would be here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview

Comment: @BrianRak Thanks for the info. I will try the same.